# Definition of a limit at infinity in which $x\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, definition

I was wondering, what is the definition of a limit in which $x$ tends to $+\infty$ and the result is $+\infty$?

Example:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\ln x = \infty$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For every $L>0$, there exists some $M>0$, for every $x\geq M$, then $f(x)\geq L$.

Whether or not those inequalities are strict does not matter.

Comment: I avoid using $\epsilon$ because that usually reserves for small numbers.

Comment: There is no need to use $>0$. It doesn't change anything either way.

Comment: Of course, but they are equivalent. >0 is just for more intuitively sense of becoming more and more larger.

Comment: Okay. In the example I posted on my question, how would you formulate it? It is just for having an example to take as a reference. Thank you! @user284331